# Solutions to an Involution Functional Equations

Tags: functional-equations, involutions

I'm reading functional equations and how to solve them and I am very confused by one of the statements made

Let $$f(x) = f(\frac{x}{x-1})$$

then a solution would be

$$f(x) = cos log (x-1)$$

but evaluating the function

$$cos log(x-1) = cos log(\frac{x}{x-1} -1)$$
$$cos log(x-1) = cos log(\frac{1}{x-1})$$ which is not true? or am I overthinking something?

Follow up Question:

It is stated in the book that  for

$$f(x) = f(a(x))$$ and $a(x)$ is an involution $f(f(f...(x)...) = x$

then $f(x)$ can be written as $$ T(x,a(x)) $$ where $T(a,b) = T(b,a)$

I dont know how to approach solving for the symmetric function $T(a,b)$.

Comment: $$\cos \log \bigg(\frac{1}{x-1} \bigg) = \cos \big(-\log (x-1) \big) = \cos \log (x-1)$$ so there is no problem.

Comment: ahh totally slipped my mind, I actually need to sleep, do you have any idea about tackling the 2nd question?

Answer (score 1):

The question about $\, f(x) = T(x, a(x))\,$ is very easy.
The general result is that
$$ f(x) = F(x \!+\! a(x), x\, a(x)) \tag1$$ satisfies the
equation $\, f(x) = f(a(x))\,$ where $\,F(.,.)\,$ is any function
provided that $\, a(a(x)) = x\,$ is for all $\,x\,$ is assumed.

A power series for which $\,f(f(x))=x,\,$ $\,f(0)=0,\,$
and $\,f'(0)\ne 0\,$ is given by
$$ a(x) - -x + c_2 x^2 - c_2^2 x^3 + c_4 x^4 + 
 (2 c_2^4 - 3c_2 c_4) x^5 + c_6 x^6 + O(x^7) \tag2$$
where $\,c_2,c_4,c_6,\dots\,$ are arbitrary. This implies that,
except for $\,f(0)=0,\,$ the even part of $\,f(x)\,$ is arbitrary
and the odd part is uniquely determined by the even part.
Several examples of these are given in [the OEIS](https://oeis.org).
For example, the generating function of [OEIS sequence A000245](https://oeis.org/A000245).

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-For the solution $f(x)=\cos(\log(x-1))$ we can do as follows: Since $f(x) = f(\dfrac{x}{x-1})$ we can verify that $f(x) - f(\dfrac{x}{x-1})=0$.

In fact $$\cos(\log(x-1))-\cos(\log(\dfrac{1}{x-1})=-2\sin\frac{\log(x-1)+\log(\frac{1}{x-1})}{2}\sin\frac{\log(x-1)-\log(\frac{1}{x-1})}{2}$$ The first factor is equal to $0$ because its numerator is $\log 1=0$.

Comment: I have put directly $\frac{x}{x-1}-1=\frac{1}{x-1}$